# Functional Difference between NUnit and MSTest in VS

Tags: database, nunit, mstest

We are using VS Community 2015 and have the choice of developing under the MSTest or the NUnit framework. We are building a testing framework using [Legitest](http://www.legitest.com/) (unit, integration, system, etc) for database testing (including ETL, OLAP and Reporting).

I have seen mentions of '[limitations of MSTest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38063903/vs-2013-mstest-vs-nunit-vs-xunit)' but for the above testing types what are the advantages of using NUnit over MSTest?

Comment: Check out the answer to this question over at [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554018/unit-test-nunit-or-visual-studio). I use NUnit with Bamboo because of the plugins that run the tests and then parse the results. And technically [VSTest replaced MSTest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182486.aspx) in 2012, but has been kept around for backwards compatibility.

Comment: @kirbycope I think that should be an answer, you can copy paste the main points and reference the link for more detailed reading, but it's a pretty solid answer.

Comment: Indeed @kirbycope. Certainly helpful and wasnt aware of VSTest

Comment: Per your suggestions I have copied relevant info into an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the answer to this question over at [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554018/unit-test-nunit-or-visual-studio).

> (From the accepted answer) NUnit has few advantages over MS-Test
>
> 1. Suite attribute - can aggregate tests and execute them separately (useful for large projects with fast and slow tests for example)
> 2. Readable Assert method, e.g. Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual) vs Assert.That(actual, Is.EqualTo(expected))
> 3. NUnit has frequent version updates - MS-Test has only one per VS version.
> 4. Many integrated runners including Resharper and TestDriven.NET
> 5. Expected exception message assertion - can be done using attribute in NUnit but must be done using Try-Catch in MS-Test
> 6. [TestCase]! NUnit allows for parameter-ized tests.

I use NUnit with Bamboo because of the plugins that run the tests and then parse the results. And technically [VSTest replaced MSTest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182486.aspx) in 2012, but has been kept around for backwards compatibility.

> You can use the VSTest.Console.exe program to run automated unit and coded UI tests from a command line. VSTest.Console.exe is optimized for performance and is **used in place of MSTest.exe** in Visual Studio 2012.